# how to fix ImportError in django when trying to import json?

Tags: ajax, django, sqlite, dropdown

i have a webpage that includes 2 chained dropdownlist  coutries and cities where based on the selection of the first the second dropdownlist display the cities belongs to the selected country.

the problem is that the first dropdownlist is displaying the fetched data from the database  but the second one  is still  empty. and the system display the below error :

> from django.utils import json as simplejson ImportError: cannot
>   import name 'json' from 'django.utils'

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
    class country(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.name)

    class city(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        MouhafazatID = models.ForeignKey(country,on_delete=models.CASCADE)


        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.name)
```

## urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # path('', home),
    path('', home2),
    path('getdetails/', getdetails),
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from testapp.models import *

from django.utils import json as simplejson # i think this is the error?



def home2(request):
    countries = country.objects.all()
    print(countries)
    return render(request, 'home2.html',{'countries': countries})



def getdetails(request):

    #country_name = request.POST['country_name']
    country_name = request.GET['cnt']
    print ("ajax country_name ", country_name)

    result_set = []
    all_cities = []

    answer = str(country_name[1:-1])
    selected_country = country.objects.get(name=answer)
    print ("selected country name ", selected_country)

    all_cities = selected_country.city_set.all()
    for city in all_cities:
        print ("city name", city.name)
        result_set.append({'name': city.name})

    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(result_set), mimetype='application/json', content_type='application/json')
```

## the last line makes the error how to fix it ?

## home2.html

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yourjavascript.com/7174319415/script.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                 $('select#selectcountries').change(function () {
                     var optionSelected = $(this).find("option:selected");
                     var valueSelected  = optionSelected.val();
                     var country_name   = optionSelected.text();


                     data = {'cnt' : country_name };
                     ajax('/getdetails',data,function(result){

                            console.log(result);
                            $("#selectcities option").remove();
                            for (var i = result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                                $("#selectcities").append('<option>'+ result[i].name +'</option>');
                            };


                         });
                 });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <select name="selectcountries" id="selectcountries">
        {% for item in countries %}
            <option val="{{ item.name }}"> {{ item.name }} </option>    
        {% endfor %}
        </select>   


        <select name ="selectcities" id="selectcities">


        </select>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i was able to fix this problem with changing the

```
from django.utils import json as simplejson
```

**to**

```
import json as simplejson
```